# NullPointerException with onClickListener for elements in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm having a hell of a time getting fragments to work. The basis of this is to lave a login screen (fragment) appear by default when `LoginActivity` is created. The fragment has an TextView that when clicked, is supposed to launch a new fragment (form for lost password). I keep getting a NullPointerException when calling `forgottenPassword.setOnClickListener` from LoginActivity.

The project crashes before I can tell if anything else works.

I'm sure there's some glaring newbie error in here somewhere...

`onCreate` method from `LoginActivity.java`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        int fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.login_screen_fragment, new FragmentLogin())
                .commit();
    }


    // Listen for FORGOTTEN PASSWORD click event, open ForgottenPassword Fragment //
    final TextView forgottenPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_lost_pass);

    forgottenPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do what I need this to do...
        }
    });
}
```

`layout_login.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_screen_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
/>
```

`fragment_login`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="come.xxxx.xxxx.ForgottenPasswordFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_email"
            android:id="@+id/login_forgot"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/login_send_lost_pass"
            android:id="@+id/button_lost_pass"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

`fragment_lost_password.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxxx.xxx.FragmentLogin">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="I forgot my password"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/login_forgot"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

`FragmentLogin.java`:

```
public class FragmentLogin extends Fragment {

    public FragmentLogin() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();

    }
}
```

`FragmentLostPassword.java`

```
public class FragmentForgottenPassword extends Fragment {

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forgotten_password, container, false);
    }
}
```

Error Trace:

```
05-13 12:49:37.222 15163-15163/com.xxxxx.xxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.xxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 15163
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.xxxxx/com.xxxxx.xxxxx.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
             at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:51)
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
05-13 12:50:28.592 15163-15173/com.xxxxx.xxxxx W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.077ms
05-13 12:50:44.622 15163-15163/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15163 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post the error trace you get?

Comment: There is not a TextView which id is `button_lost_pass` in your xml

Comment: where is this id in your xmal R.id.button_lost_pass

Comment: @GunjanVerma - I saw and corrected the reference in XML, but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your fragment might be not accessible when you assign forgetpassword , you can use the following for layout_login.xml:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:name="FragmentLogin"  
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login"
    />
```

Note you may have to define the right path to FragmentLogin.
This is the new way to work with fragment, that will load your Login fragment automatically without writing anything in onCreate.

Also, it's not a TextView but a Button

Finally, remove the Fragment Transaction code.

Another option, is to move your forgot password button login to FragmentLogin. Because basically you try to access Fragment related element from the activity. Everything should be in your fragment. 
You can still access the fragment manager with getActivity().getFragmentManger(), to load the lost_password layout.

Comment: Thanks. My mixing up the TextView and Button aside, this all boiled down to not having the 'android:name' in the fragment defined.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the View in your Fragment's layout.
Use the following in your FragmentLogin class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    final TextView forgottenPassword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button_lost_pass);
    // Set your onClickListener here

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the activity_login.xml content. I guest wrong id of button button_lost_pass

Comment: Added. So much to paste, forgot that one.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);  So you set layout to activity_login.xml. But your button is inside fragment_login. So you need to define your button inside fragment, not in activity.

Answer (score 0):

Inside oncreate() method you called new Fragment but the fragment layout(layout_lost_password) does not contain the id(R.id.button_lost_pass)

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
final TextView forgottenPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_lost_pass);
```

To

```
final Button forgottenPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_lost_pass);
```